# Regex "NOT" in Google Sheets (RE2)

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, re2

I want to check if in a cell there is one word but not another. In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28775466/google-sheet-regexreplace-match-everything-except-a-particular-pattern) there was some buzz around this matter but the elected solution included a script function. There has to be an easier way to do that.

I want to check if in the string "investimentos" the string "investimentos" is present and "fundos" is not.

I've already tried those below (disclaimer: I'm a beginner with regex):

```
=regexmatch("investimentos";"(investimentos)^(fundos)")
=regexmatch("investimentos";"(investimentos).*^(fundos)")
=regexmatch("investimentos";"(investimentos)(^fundos)")
=regexmatch("investimentos";"(investimentos).*(^fundos)")
```

I'm always getting false. Why is that?

Comment: Same as in my previous answer: there is no lookaround support in RE2, so you cannot use that logic in the RE2 expression. Use `=AND(REGEXMATCH(A1;"word1");NOT(REGEXMATCH(A1;"word2")))`

Comment: thanks. your again.

Comment: You could do that with a single regex if the negated value is just 1 character. Like `^[^I]*GO[^I]*$` will match a string that has no `I` but contains `GO`, but in case there are multiple chars in that word, it won't work.

Comment: https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax

Comment: Regarding the edits in this question, I have given way on the title, even if I tend to think of all-caps material as a bit shouty. However, I have removed the request to readers of "shining a light on it" as that is rather vague, and is not as readily understandable as "Why does X happen". We have guidance on vague questions [in this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question), which is worth a read.

Comment: [The Stack Overflow `regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info) has some general notes on negation in regular expressions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no lookaround support in [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax), so you cannot use the common logic to [match one string excluding another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953039/regular-expression-for-a-string-containing-one-word-but-not-another).

You could do that with a single regex if the negated value is just 1 character. Like `^[^I]*GO[^I]*$` will match a string that has no `I` but contains `GO`, but in case there are multiple chars in the word you want to exclude, it won't work.

Use

```
=AND(REGEXMATCH(A1;"investimentos");NOT(REGEXMATCH(A1;"fundos")))
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=(REGEXMATCH(A1; "investimentos"))*(NOT(REGEXMATCH(A1; "fundos")))
```

or:

```
=(REGEXMATCH(A1; "investimentos"))*(REGEXMATCH(A1; "[^fundos]"))
```

Comment: Hi @player0 is it possible to do the same with a query formula while keeping the blank cels vertically? I have this formula that works but it filters intermediary blank cells: `=QUERY(B10:B,"SELECT B WHERE B MATCHES '.+(\.|\?|\!|\.\.\.)[\sA-Z].+|.+[a-z(\.|\?|\!|\.\.\.)]$' AND NOT B MATCHES 'Zn(\.|\?|\!|\.\.\.)[\sA-Z].+|.+[a-z(\.|\?|\!|\.\.\.)]$'",0)`

Comment: This one is equivalent to the Query formula above and gives the expected result with intermediary blank cells `=IFNA(ArrayFormula(
IFS(ISNUMBER(B10:B),"",
REGEXMATCH(B10:B,".+(\.|\?|\!|\.\.\.)[\sA-Z].+|(.+\.)$")=FALSE,"",
(REGEXMATCH(B10:B,".+(\.|\?|\!|\.\.\.)[\sA-Z].+|(.+\.)$")) * 
(NOT(REGEXMATCH(B10:B,"Zn(\.|\?|\!|\.\.\.)[\sA-Z].+"))),B10:B)),"")` But I'd prefer using the Query formula if possible.

Answer (score 1):

If, like me, you're trying to use regexmatch within a filter function, the combination of *and* and *not* functions doesn't seem to work - I'm not sure why but the error suggests it's only returning one row, rather than all the rows the positive and negative regexmatch functions match too.

However, *@player0's suggestion of combining the `*` and `not` functions to combine the positive and negative `regexmatch` functions does work.* So, for example:

```
=filter('Sheet 1'!B:B,(regexmatch('Sheet 1'!$D:$D,"Positive Search Term"))*not(regexmatch('Sheet 1'!$D:$D,"Negative Search Term")))
```