# How to use ARRAYFORMULA for REPLACE function in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, array-formulas, finance

G'day, I'm working on a finance project using Google Sheets and I think I'm getting in a bit over my head.

I am trying to reformat a list of transactions by truncating the date (mm/dd/yyyy and a space) so that I can sort them alphabetically. I tried to do this quickly using an `ARRAYFORMULA`, but it did not seem to work as I wanted to. I'm using it in conjunction with the `REPLACE` formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REPLACE(A2, 1, 11, "")
```

I've made an [spreadsheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uIatl5DKOKffrMblryc4acPowx0gdp17S5oIsV4tDxY/edit?usp=sharing) to exemplify the problem.

It doesn't throw an error, but it also doesn't generate a full array. I would be most grateful if someone could explain why this isn't working, or perhaps clarify the way `ARRAYFORMULA` function is supposed to work.

Thanks!

Comment: We need a (X)`*`(Y) =1  construct instead of `AND` for a negative match combined with a positive match case as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43710932/10789707 vs here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54835596/10789707 for it to work with the arrayformula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
=Arrayformula(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A,"^\S+","")))
```

[image]

Comment: Even though the spreadsheets functions are generally case-insensitive, the RE2 expressions are case-sensitive, correct? (particularly with that \S character)

Comment: Yes "\S" is case sensitive